# ASP MVC - Form input types and model binding issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I am playing around with server-side form validation, model binding and ModelState and I’ve noticed the following:

- If I have an input of type “email” and I insert an invalid email
  address (such as ‘hello’), model binding doesn’t work – the value
  shows up as ‘null’.
- However, if I insert a valid email address,
  everything works out.

Can someone explain to me why this happens?
Thanks in advance!

**Form:**

```
<form name="contactForm" id="contactF" ng-controller="Contacts"  ng-submit="contactForm.$invalid ? sendMessage() : return;" novalidate>   
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="model.EmailAddress" required placeholder="Email"/>
    <div ng-messages="contactForm.email.$error" ng-if="contactForm.email.$touched || contactForm.$submitted">
        <div ng-messages-include="/Helpers/error-messages.html"></div>
    </div>

    <textarea name="message" ng-model="model.message" required placeholder="Escreva a sua mensagem aqui."></textarea>
    <div ng-messages="contactForm.message.$error" ng-if="contactForm.message.$touched || contactForm.$submitted">
        <div ng-messages-include="/Helpers/error-messages.html"></div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

**Model:**

```
public class HomeContactVM 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error message here")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error msg here.")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please use a valid email address.")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error msg here.")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

**Action method:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Contact(HomeContactVM model) 
{
    string message;
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient()) 
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage()
            {
                Body = model.Message,
                BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                Subject = "New message from " + model.EmailAddress,
                From = new MailAddress(model.EmailAddress),
                Sender = new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com", "xx")
            };

            int retries = 5;
            bool retry = true;
            while (retry) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    client.Send(msg);
                    message = "Your message was sent.";
                    return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                catch (Exception) 
                {
                    if (retries > 0) {
                                retries--;
                    }
                    else {
                        retry = false;
                        message = "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                        return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    message = "Your model is not valid.";
    return Json( message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Your model property is `EmailAddress`, but the input name is `email` - one of those is incorrect.

Comment: your input type is email, how it is passing the html validation anyway, It shouldn't allow submit., it will show you a message invalid email, the only way it won't validate is when it is empty, but your input is required so it will validate empty as well. that is strange

Comment: Tieson T - just changed it and the issue remains (model binding only works if the email address is valid); Munzer - you're talking about client-side validation? it's passing because of the AngularJS $invalid I added to the ng-submit directive (I did that just so that I could bypass client-side validation and test server-side validation)

Answer (score 0):

So, if anyone is facing the same problem, here's what I found: the problem is not related to ASP, it's due to Angular's default behaviour. 
If an input fails validation, Angular sets its value to undefined and it doesn't pass it to the model, hence it showing up as null. A possible workaround is to set ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"

You can find more about this behaviour here: [Angular.js - ngModel value is undefined when ng-pattern is set in directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301290/angular-js-ngmodel-value-is-undefined-when-ng-pattern-is-set-in-directive) and [Get "raw" value from invalid input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817602/get-raw-value-from-invalid-input-field)

Hope this helps!